# Visual studio is scrolling past window

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

[image]
Since yesterday visual studios started to scroll past the normal window. It is as if there is base interface window above another window. I don't know if it is a bug or i activated this with a hotkey by mistake. This happens every time i scroll down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that going to the debug console on my terminal tab would cause the window to scroll up. So I went to settings and typed `debug` then i deselected.
`Debug › Console: Word Wrap`

Problem solved!!